# facebook login button is crashing when you click

Tags: android, android-facebook

Problem:
  `fb button is crashing` .

Crash report:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment com.facebook.internal.FragmentWrapper.getSupportFragment()' on a null object reference
```

I have updated my android studio to 2.0 and I started having problems with the compilation of the app.

1. I have changed 
       `renderscriptTargetApi 23` to `renderscriptTargetApi 20`
2. fb compile from compile `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0'` to `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'`

   error msg: `Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').`

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

The same code was working till now .It has    `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" in the activity in manifest file and build.gradle` has

```
 compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
```

But it crashes and displays the error now:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment com.facebook.internal.FragmentWrapper.getSupportFragment()' on a null object reference
```

How can I fix it?

main.xml

```
     <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

            facebook:com_facebook_login_text="login"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Comment: Have you defined FacebookActivity in xml?

Comment: it's not readable in comment post this in your question

Comment: @VivekMishra I have added the code I have used for the button in xml.

Comment: Even if I change fragmentActivity to Activity , I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing this same problem, then I change the version of my facebook SDK from **4.8.0** to **4.13.1**

Then, I add this

```
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
    force = true
}
```

to solve the cardView error.